# Error Index out of Bound when trying to write data to new .txt file

Tags: python, csv, data-manipulation, txt, cartesian-coordinates

I am trying to write a specific portion of data from a .txt file to a different .txt file for later use.

Code is below.

```
file = open(path, newline='')
reader = csv.reader(file)

header = next(reader)
data = [row for row in reader]

#read only cartesian points to new text file
f = open("Cartesian Points.txt", "w+")
#create a range from the first cartesian point 75054 to the last 1048576
for i in range(data[75054],data[1048576],1):
    f.write(data[i])
f.close()
```

My idea is to parse the original file completely, then create a range for the cartesian points and write this to a different .txt file for later use.

However when writing the data I am receiving an error

```
    for i in range(data[75054],data[1048576],1):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am confused as I know that the data ranges from cell 75054 to 1048576 and it should simply write that data to the new .txt file. I don't see why the data would continue on past the specified range.

Comment: Did you try to print `len(data)`? Do you really get a value bigger than 1048576?

Comment: I suggest *print(len(data))* before entering the loop. You'll probably find the output very interesting

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't want `range(75054, 1048576,1)` ?

Comment: Off-by-one error? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Comment: as suggested use print or even logging (or debug your variable step by step if your IDE support it, PyCharm does) to see the actual value of data[]

Comment: printing that gives me 1048575, however when changing the end of the range to `data[1048575]` I still receive the same error.

Comment: @nonDucor don't I need to reference the data by using `data[some arbitrary number]` to properly start and end the range?

Comment: If you want to write in the output the rows from 75054 to 1048576, that's what should be on your range (because these are the values of `i`, which is an index). When you do `f.write(data[i])` then you'll get the value of the row to write in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `for i in range(data[75054],data[1048576],1)` actually takes the content of `data` at position *75054* as integer number for the `range()` function.

From your question it seems you want to cycle inside the range 75054 <-> 1048576. This can be achived with `for i in range(75054,1048576,1)`

With the code

```
for i in range(75054,1048576):
    f.write(data[i])
```

You cycle from *75054* to *1048576* and write into the file (object `f`) the content of `data[i]` at the position `i` (which is an integer inside the cycle)

In the example above the `1` at the end in `range()` has been removed because it's set to `1` as default by Python itself

Some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) about `range()`. You may also want to check [lists in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)